# SQL Sever Query Join Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, optimization

I have looked for answers online but cant find a definitive answer. For example you have 2 join clauses:

1.

```
JOIN T2 ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
```

2.

```
JOIN T2 ON T1.[ID] = REPLACE(T2.[ID],'A', '')
```

Now the 2nd one performs worse due to the function on the join clause. What is the exact reason for this?

And for example, if this code was in a stored procedure what would be best to optimise it? To remove the replace function and add it to the table level so all of this is completed before any joins?

Any advice or links to further information would be great. Thanks

Comment: The second `JOIN`'s argument is not [sargable](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/). That word's not in the dictionary, but it is the key term you want to use to investigate this issue.

Comment: When you apply a function to a join argument or field in a WHERE clause the server can't use any indexes on that field. The index was created using the field's values while the query wants to use *different* values. In order to generate those values the server *has* to scan the entire table

Comment: BTW why would an *ID* contain anything that needs replacement? Perhaps it's two fields posing as one? A bad design - keys should have no business meaning that can or needs to change

Comment: stay on the first join and add a condition to exclude t2 'A' records. then union the select using all t2 'a' rows and join again directly -- see bellow my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, you are attempting to find a record in T2 - but instead of the value being the T1.ID value, you are applying a function to T2.ID -  `REPLACE(T2.[ID],'A', '')`

If you had an index on T2.ID - at best it would scan the index and not seek it - thus causing a performance difference.

This is where it get's harder to explain - the index is stored as a b+tree, of the values for the T2.ID on the table. The index understands that field and can search / sort by it, but it doesn't understand any logic applied to it.

It does not know if `REPLACE('A123','A', '') = 123` - without in executing the function on the value in the index and checking the resulting equality.

AAA123 would also be equal, 1A23, 12A3, 123A etc, there is a never ending amount of combinations that would in fact match - but the only way in which it can figure out if a single index entry matches is to run that value through the function and then check the equality.

If it can only figure that out when running the index value through the function - it can only properly answer the query correctly if it does that for every entry in the index - e.g. an index scan of every entry, being passed into the function and the output being checked.

As Jeroen mentions the term is SARGable or SARGability, `S`earch `ARG`ument`ABLE`, although I personally prefer to explain it as `S`eek `ARG`ument`ABLE` since that is a closer match to the query plan operator.

It should be noted that this concept has nothing to do with it being a join, any predicate within SQL has this restriction - a single table query with a where predicate can have the same issue.

Can this problem be avoided? It can but only in some instances, where you can reverse the operation.

Consider a table with an ID column, I could construct a predicate such as this :
`WHERE ID * 2 = @paramValue`

The only way SQL Server would know if an ID entry multiplied by 2 is the passed in value is to process every entry, double it and check. So that is the index scan scenario again.

In this instance we can re-write it:
`WHERE ID = @paramValue / 2.0`

Now SQL Server will perform the mathematics once, divide the passed in value and it can then check that against the index in a seekable manner. The difference in the SQL written looks a potentially trivial difference of stating the problem, but makes a very large difference to how the database can resolve the predicate.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has four basic methods for handling joins (as do other databases):

1. Nested loop without an index.  This is like two nested `for` loops and is usually the slowest method.
2. Index looped (nested loop with an index).  This a scan of one table with a lookup in the second.
3. Merge join.  This assumes that the two tables are ordered and loops through the two tables at the same time (this can also be accomplished using indexes).
4. Hash join.  The keys for the two tables are hashed and hash-tables are used for matching.

In general, the first of these is the slowestthe second of these -- using an index -- is the fastest.  (There are exceptions).  The second is often the fastest.

When you use an equality comparison between two columns in the table, SQL Server has a lot of information for deciding on the best join algorithm to use:

- It has information on indexes.
- It has statistics on the column.

Without this information, SQL Server often defaults to the nested-loop join.  I find that it does this even when it could use the expression for a merge- or hash- based join.

As a note, you can work around this by using a computed column:

```
alter table t2 add id_no_a as (replace(id, 'A', '')) persisted;

create index idx_t2_id_no_a on t2(id_no_a);
```

Then phrase

```
on T1.[ID] = t2.id_no_a
```

Answer (score -2):

Example of using union to avoid searches without index:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID VARCHAR(16), CODE INT)
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID VARCHAR(16), CODE INT)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('ASD',1)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('DFG',2)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('RTY',3)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('AZX',4)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('GTY',5)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('KKO',6)

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('ASD',1)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('SD',2)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('DFG',3)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('RTY',4)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('AZX',5)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('ZX',6)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('GTY',7)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('GTYA',8)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('KKO',9)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('KKOA',10)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('AKKOA',11)



SELECT * FROM @T1 T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM @T2 WHERE ID NOT LIKE '%A%')T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM @T1 T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT REPLACE(ID,'A','')ID FROM @T2 WHERE ID LIKE '%A%')T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```

This is what you can do without schema changes.
With schema changes you need to create a calculated indexed column into T2 and join with it. This is is much faster and most of the effort is placed on inserts/updates to maintain the extra column and the index on it.

Comment: This proposed replacement fails for `T1.ID = 'BNN'` and `T2.ID = 'BANANA'`. It would be correct only if we knew that the only value for `T2.ID` that contained an `A` was, in fact, exactly `A` and nothing else.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert right i got mistaken with replace fun. Still my solution do the job with indexed search at all times.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Even if `ID` is fully indexed, `LIKE '%A%'` isn't sargable, so you're still getting a full index scan on the second part regardless. You can verify this by adding an index on ID to the tables. Overall this query is very slightly slower than what the optimizer produces on its own -- splitting the conditions just doesn't add much in this case. This technique does have some applications in case one (or both) halves do allow seeks and the optimizer isn't clever enough to see it, but in this case it just makes it more complicated for no gain.

Comment: Yes ok, but the main difference here is that cardinality estimator cannot estimate properly the number of rows in case of JOIN T2 ON T1.[ID] = REPLACE(T2.[ID],'A', ''). In my case the estimator can estimate the returned rows more accurately which is very important. The estimation of rows greatly affects execution plan selection. I just do not want to get it that deep. But you are right - there is now way to go better than full index search when dealing with LIKE.